# Read form input element name via $_Files

Tags: php

I have a form with an inputs similar to this:

```
<p><label>Image 1: </label><input type="file" name="candy"></p>
<p><label>Image 2: </label><input type="file" name="apple"></p>
<p><label>Image 3: </label><input type="file" name="red"></p>
```

Using a loop through $_Files, I'm wondering if it is possible to get the input field name (not value) of the uploaded file's input element?

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
  /*
  do image processing here, but would like to save as 
  'candy.jpg' rather than $file['name'].
  */
}
```

So I want to be able to get the field name 'candy' or 'apple' without knowing what it is. Everything I've seen so far assumes that 'candy' will already be known when handling the file.

In other words, I want to work backwards from the uploaded file to the element it was uploaded from. Is this possible with PHP?

UPDATED with the solution:

```
foreach($_FILES as $key=>$file) { 
  $image = new Imagick($file['tmp_name']); 
  // do some processing 
  $image->writeImage($key.'.jpg'); 
}
```

Will give 'candy.jpg' or 'apple.jpg' depending on the input field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request the key in a `foreach` statement.

```
foreach($_FILES as $key=>$file) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach($_FILES as $nameOfInputFile => $file) {

    // your stuff

}
```

`$_FILES` is an array which have as index the name(s) of your inputs (of type file)